# Dictionary of two different type and convert as JSON

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a Json file write as follow :

```
{
    "KeyString1": "ValueString1",
    "KeyListOfDict": [
        {
            "KeyString2": "ValueString2",
            "KeyDict2": {
                "KeyString3": "ValueString3"                
            }
        },
        {
            "KeyString4": "ValueString4",
            "KeyDict2": {
                "KeyString5": "ValueString5"                
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to access "ValueString3" and "ValueString5" but I can't manage to Deserialize in a Dictionary.

`dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);`

Because of the several value type in the dictinary I don't know to make the thing work.

Can you help to find a way to use this Json file ?

Comment: If your structure isn't regular (key names, values types...) you can deserialize your JSON to an [anonymous type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `JObject`

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
var resultToDict = JObject.Parse(json)["KeyListOfDict"]
                   .Select(p => (((JProperty)p["KeyDict2"].Children().First()).Name, ((JProperty)p["KeyDict2"].Children().First()).Value))
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
```

> the result you can able access with the property name.